# Proof that the DE corresponds to a mapping of circle.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm struggling with the differential equation :
$${d^2r\over dt^2} = i{dr\over dt}$$
I know from physics that this is just circular motion(acceleration is normal to velocity.)but stated this way confuses me. How do i prove this is a circle?

Comment: Hint: setting $\frac{dr}{dt}=u$, the equation reduces to $u'=iu$, and it's solutions are $u(t)=C e^{it}$.

Comment: Oh,it so obvious now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the comment suggests:
$$u(t) =  Ce^{it}$$
By the euler formula we have :$$Ce^{it}=C(\cos(t)+i\sin(t))$$
Which is the polar form of the equation of the circle.